# Anonymize data in select statement

Tags: sql, anonymous

We have a requirement to anonymize user columns, so they show NULL instead of the username.
Though of doing this

`case when 1 = 1 then NULL else NULL end as USERNAME`
But of course this doesn't work: *At least one of the result expressions in a CASE specification must be an expression other than the NULL constant.*
Is there a cleaner way to anonymize data in a select statement?

Comment: What's wrong with simply returning `NULL as USERNAME`? No need for a `CASE` statement.

Comment: If the requirement is to return a column with all `NULL`s with name "USERNAME" why are you using `CASE 1=1`? Just use `CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS UserName` or whatever the desired datatype is

Comment: Why not simply return an empty string? `'' AS USERNAME`

Comment: Don't grant select on columns with restricted access data.